# How to create a heatmap in Android using compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to create a heatmap using jetpack compose in Android? I have implemented maps-compose and maps-compose-utils and have successfully created a Google map with clustering, but I can't find anywhere a way to implement a heatmap in compose or any documentation about it.

Is this feature still missing in compose and I'm stuck with using maps in xml, or has anyone found a way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/taewooyo/volcano ?